# Induction involving an $n$ th root of $n!$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

[image]

I am almost through with this induction , but somehow the last step looks a miss! Is there any intervention on the inequality with the half , to help in the conclusion?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with functional analysis...

Comment: Can that be true?  If $n > 1$ then $n! > 1$ and $\sqrt{n!} > 1$ and $n\sqrt{n!} > n\cdot 1 = n$.  But $\frac {n+1}2 < \frac {n+n}2 = n$.  SO I don't see how this can be true at all!

Comment: @fleablood Is $\sqrt[n]{n!}$ instead of $n\sqrt{n!}$.

Comment: Ah, well that makes sense then.  Hint: consider the AM-GM inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prove, by induction, that $$\sqrt[n]{n!}\leq \frac{n+1}{2}$$
For $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

---

For $n=1$, we see that
$$
\sqrt[1]{1}\leq\frac{2}{2}
$$
Let us assume that the inequality holds for $n=k$:
\begin{align}
\sqrt[k]{k!}&\leq\frac{k+1}{2} \\
k!&\leq\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)^k \\
k!&\leq\frac{(k+1)^k}{2^k} \\
2^kk!&\leq(k+1)^k
\end{align}
Using this fact, we want to show that the inequality holds for $n=k+1$. In other words, that
$$
2^{k+1}(k+1)!\leq(k+2)^{k+1}
$$
Returning to
$$
2^kk!\leq(k+1)^k
$$
We see that, if we multiply both sides by $2(k+1)$, we get
$$
2^{k+1}(k+1)!\leq2(k+1)^{k+1}
$$
Now all we have to show is that
$$
2(k+1)^{k+1}\leq(k+2)^{k+1}
$$
Luckily, this is easier than it looks. If we solve the equation
$$
2u^u=(u+1)^u
$$
with $u=k+1$, then we'll be very close to the answer.
$$
2=\left(\frac{u+1}{u}\right)^u
$$
Does the RHS look familiar to you? If you need help completing the proof, just ask.